# php mySql Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good Day, I am learning Php Using Larave. I am following this [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpcNVJEB2G4&list=PLB4AdipoHpxaHDLIaMdtro1eXnQtl_UvE&index=13) of tutorial. So far I don't have any encountered error. But at this video at `08:02` mins I don't know where/how did he add those columns.

I followed his tutorial which he only added the following Bio, Photo and Type
in User.php inside the project.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','bio','photo','type'
];
```

But when I inspect my mySql table it didn't add those columns unlike to the video.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i just watched that video, he has all those fields in the mysql table, watch this closely [video time](https://youtu.be/lpcNVJEB2G4?t=408) and the [screen shot](https://snipboard.io/AIRVLb.jpg), you should watch all the videos if you are following that tutorial he probably created those fields when he created migrations.

Comment: I watched the video from the start. But I didn't see any video that is related in creating that table.

Comment: maybe you can ask the comment on the video to ask clarifications about the tutorial.

Comment: here is the migration file link from his [github](https://github.com/Hujjat/laravStart/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php) please include these fields in your migrations and run `php artisan migrate:refresh` this will delete all the data from your database and create new database with the new fields. if you want to learn about migrations please consult [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations)

Comment: I was thinking about it. My only hope is if viewers are active.

Comment: Thank you, You save me. I Having an error but I solved it. Because in DB it was not null. Please update you answer. This code `php artisan migrate:refresh` solve my issue

Comment: @OmarAbbas it would be well if you'd break down what the solution was in your answer. In the future those links might break.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin tha's a good suggestion, but for this specific case it was need, also i think this question won't be helpful for other users I guess as it is a very specific question about a youtube tutorial and i also explained a bit in the comment, but i will defiantly keep that in mind form now on before answering my questions. thank you for your suggestion, really appreciate it.